# Google App Engine database not getting displayed

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have created an entity 'FlipKart' in my application, and have used a handler where I have run a query so that I can display the given entry in my HTML form. I have Jinja2 template for organizing my html file.

Here's the code for the entity:

```
class FlipKart(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()            
    quantity = db.IntegerProperty()
    total = db.IntegerProperty()
```

Here's the handler where I process and run my query:

```
class WebeHandler(Handler):         
    def get(self):
        self.render("we.html")
    def post(self):
        b_name = self.request.get("bkname")
        b_quantity = self.request.get("qnty")
        b_total = self.request.get("tot")        

        if(b_name and b_quantity and b_total):
            a = FlipKart(BookName = b_name, Quantity = b_quantity, GrandTotal = b_total)
            a.put()
            self.final()
    def final(self):
        flips = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM FlipKart")
        self.render("we.html", flips = flips)
```

Here's my html file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Web Engineering</title>
    <style type = "text/css">

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <form method = "post">
        Book Name<input type = "text" name = "bkname">
        <br>
        Quantity<input type = "text" name = "qnty">
        <br>
        Total Prize<input type = "number" name = "tot">
        <br>
        <input type = "submit">
        <br><br><br>
        <hr>

        {%
            for flip in flips
        %}
            <div>You have ordered a {{flip.name}}</div>
        {%endfor%}
    </form>
</body>
```

However, when I run this application, I get the following text after the form in my browser:

```
You have ordered a None
You have ordered a None
You have ordered a None
You have ordered a None
You have ordered a None
You have ordered a None
You have ordered a None
You have ordered a None
You have ordered a None
You have ordered a None
You have ordered a None
You have ordered a None
You have ordered a None
You have ordered a None
You have ordered a None
You have ordered a None
You have ordered a None
You have ordered a None
```

What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no problem with your query, you can see the loop repeats.
Your problem is your code for creating entities

`a = FlipKart(BookName = b_name, Quantity = b_quantity, GrandTotal = b_total)`

where as your model is defined as

```
class FlipKart(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()            
    quantity = db.IntegerProperty()
    total = db.IntegerProperty()
```

You aren't actually storing any of the values in the entity.  This is very basic python.

The class constructor call should be

`a = FlipKart(name = b_name, quantity = b_quantity, total = b_total)`

You need to do the int conversion as well as per the other answer, the only reason you were not getting an error with assignment is you where never assigning the values to the properties.

Also note your query may not show the most recent entity added due to eventual consistancy, (I will let you do some reading on that)

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to point out that you will probably want to restructure your entity to enable you to make strongly consistent queries as you will continue to get a None, for newly added entities even after making the corrections that have already been pointed out.

This is due to eventual consistency. Please review: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency